# Thread-safe queue mechanism

Tags: c#

Is it my queue mechanism thread safe? I just wonder if I need concurrent collections. Need I lock Enqueue method? Console displays queue count in incorrect order, Does it affect on maxQueueCount at Load method? Can I improve it in some way? I want queue with a maximum size, and I don't want the same item to be enqueued again.

I have many database sources with stored procedures which select documents. Each document has a unique Id but may be contained in many data sources. So I need to check if the document with the specified ID is processed in my data flow or not. I don't want to clogged my queue so If queue count equals = 1000 I don't want to enqueue new documents.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

class Program
{
    public class Document : IItem
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var queueProvider = new Provider();
        var docs = new List<IItem>
        {
            new Document { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new Document { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new Document { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new Document { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new Document { Id = Guid.NewGuid() }
        };

        try
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var timer1 = new Timer(1000) { Interval = 1000 };
                timer1.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    queueProvider.Load(docs, 1);
                };
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Start();
            });
            tasks.Add(task1);

            var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var timer1 = new Timer(1000) { Interval = 1000 };
                timer1.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    queueProvider.Load(docs, 2);
                };
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Start();
            });
            tasks.Add(task2);

            //Dequeue

            //var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            //{
            //    var timer1 = new Timer(3000) { Interval = 1000 };
            //    timer1.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
            //    {
            //        queueProvider.Dequeue();
            //    };
            //    timer1.Enabled = true;
            //    timer1.Start();
            //});
            //tasks.Add(task3);

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


public interface IItem
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IProvider
{
    void Enqueue(IItem feedingItem, int id);
}

public class Provider : IProvider
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<IItem> queue;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, DateTime> inputBuffor;

    private readonly object locker = new object();

    private int maxQueueCount = 3;

    public Provider()
    {
        queue = new ConcurrentQueue<IItem>();
        inputBuffor = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, DateTime>();
    }

    public IItem Dequeue()
    {
        queue.TryDequeue(out var item);

        Console.WriteLine("Dequeue: " + item.Id);

        return item;
    }

    public void Enqueue(IItem item, int id)
    {
        //lock (locker)
        //{
        if (inputBuffor.TryAdd(item.Id, DateTime.Now))
        {
            queue.Enqueue(item);

            Console.WriteLine("Enqueue: " + item.Id + "taskId: " + id);
            Console.WriteLine("Count: " + queue.Count + " Buffor: " + inputBuffor.Count);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Enqueue: " + item.Id + "taskId: " + id);
        }
        //}
    }

    public void Load(IEnumerable<IItem> data, int id)
    {
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            if (queue.Count < maxQueueCount)
                Enqueue(item, id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
I renamed Enqueu method to TryEnqueue and  added BlockingCollection instead Concurent Collection.

```
      var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var timer1 = new Timer(1000) { Interval = 1000 };
                    timer1.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        foreach(var doc in docs) 
                        {
                               if (queueProvider.TryEnqueue(doc, 1))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Enqueue: " + doc.Id + "taskId: 2");
                                Console.WriteLine("Count: " + queueProvider.QueueCount + " Buffor: " + queueProvider.BufforCount);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Not Enqueue: " + doc.Id + "taskId: 2");
                            }
                        }


                    };
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                    timer1.Start();
                });
                tasks.Add(task1);



        public bool TryEnqueue(IItem item, int id)
            {

                if (inputBuffor.TryAdd(item.Id, DateTime.Now))
                {
                    if (queue.TryAdd(item))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

 public IItem Dequeue()
    {
        queue.TryTake(out var item);

        return item;
    }
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Dequeue: " + item.Id);` What do you think will happen if `item` is `null`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no problem to solve rather it is asking for _code review_.  It might be relevant on another Stack Exchange site

Comment: `if (queue.Count < maxQueueCount)` If you exceed the count you are just going to throw the `data` away?

Comment: I forgot  to check queue count before dequeue. Yes. I  want  throw the data away if queue.Count will be greater than maxQueueCount.

Comment: `Yes. I want throw the data away if queue.Count will be greater than maxQueueCount.` Then you want to use `BlockingCollection` with a bounded capacity - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Concurrent_BlockingCollection_1__ctor_System_Int32_ . Use `TryAdd` to add - this will automatically ensure that `maxQueueCount` is not exceeded - even better it is in a way that is thread-safe (unlike your current code).

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview to learn more about `BlockingCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple threads could both satisfy `queue.Count < maxQueueCount` (at the same time) and then each thread would run your Enqueue method and push past your maxQueueCount. That is definitely not thread safe. I’d move that check into your EnqueueMethod and surround it with a lock.